# Lilypond: Single bar, multiple repeat

Tags: lilypond, repeats, lily-scheme

Drum charts are often very repetitive, so frequently a bar will have a repeat count indicated above it. Examples shown here:

[image: example of drum rhythms with percent style repeat symbols, the number of repeats is represented as a large bold number above the symbol]
(from http://www.play-drums.com/Pad/lesson11-repeats.asp)

---

I've been able to do this in LilyPond by defining a function like so:

```
make_percent = #(define-music-function ()()
  "Make a percent repeat spanning one bar"
  (make-music 'PercentEvent
             'length (ly:make-moment 1))
)

percent_repeat = #(define-music-function (count) (integer?) 
  "Make a percent repeat with a bar count above"
  #{
    \once \override Staff.MeasureCounter.text = #(number->string count)
    <>\startMeasureCount
    \make_percent
    <>\stopMeasureCount
  #}
)
```

But this is less than ideal, I'd prefer to do it through `\repeat percent` somehow, but can't find a way.

Is there a way? Is this a feature request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is currently not possible. You can trick MM rests to allow for such an behaviour, like this:

```
\version "2.22"

#(define (slash height slope thickness)
   (let* ((wid (/ height slope))
          (adjthick (/ thickness (sqrt (+ (* slope slope) 1))))
          (x0 0)
          (y0 0)
          (x1 (+ 0 adjthick))
          (y1 0)
          (x2 (+ wid adjthick))
          (y2 height)
          (x3 wid)
          (y3 height))
    (make-path-stencil
      `(moveto ,x0 ,y0 lineto ,x1 ,y1 lineto ,x2 ,y2 lineto ,x3 ,y3 lineto ,x0 ,y0)
      0.01
      1
      1
      #t)))

#(define-markup-command (slash layout props height slope thickness) (number? number? number?)
   (slash height slope thickness))

perc = \markup\concat{
  \raise #0.5 \musicglyph #"dots.dot"
  \hspace #-0.75
  \lower #1 \slash #2 #1 #0.98
  \hspace #-0.75
  \lower #0.5 \musicglyph #"dots.dot"
}

compress = \compressMMRests\etc

repeatWholeMeasure =
#(define-music-function (dur n) (ly:duration? number?)
   #{
     \temporary\override Staff.MultiMeasureRest.stencil =
     #(grob-transformer 'stencil
                        (lambda (grob orig)
                          (let* ((text (ly:text-interface::print grob))
                                 (ext-x (ly:stencil-extent orig X))
                                 (mid (interval-center ext-x))
                                 (t-ext-x (ly:stencil-extent text X))
                                 (mid2 (interval-center t-ext-x)))
                            (ly:stencil-translate-axis text (- mid mid2) X))))
     \temporary\override Staff.MultiMeasureRest.text = \perc
     \temporary\override Staff.MultiMeasureRest.spacing-pair.break-alignment = #'staff-bar
     \temporary\override Staff.MultiMeasureRest.bound-padding = #'()
     \temporary\override Staff.MultiMeasureRest.space-increment = #'()
     \temporary\override Staff.MultiMeasureRestNumber.padding = #1.5
     R $dur * $n
     \revert Staff.MultiMeasureRest.stencil
     \revert Staff.MultiMeasureRest.text
     \revert Staff.MultiMeasureRest.spacing-pair.break-alignment
     \revert Staff.MultiMeasureRest.bound-padding
     \revert Staff.MultiMeasureRest.space-increment
     \revert Staff.MultiMeasureRestNumber.padding
   #})

\new RhythmicStaff {
  4 8 8 8 8 4
  \compress \repeatWholeMeasure 1 5
}

% Advantage of this approach:

<<
  \new RhythmicStaff {
    4 8 8 8 8 4
    \compress \repeatWholeMeasure 1 5
  }
  \new RhythmicStaff {
    8 8 4 4 8 8 |
    4 4 8 8 8 8 |
    4 8 8 4 8 8 |
    4 4 4 4 |
    8 8 8 8 8 8 4 |
    4 2 8 8
  }
>>
```

but there is not really a way to collapse percent repeats. It would be most certainly doable if there is enough reason to have percent repeats compressable.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to draw the percent symbol from scratch.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Do you have a better way ready, or do you ask this out of interest?

Comment: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/short-repeats  shows a way to get an isolated percent repeat symbol

Comment: I assume you could use that^ or something like it to draw the symbol.  But maybe you have a good reason for drawing it from scratch, if so I'd like to know what that reason is.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace If you are referring to the point _Isolated percent repeats_: This one creates a percent event, which is then (by the respective engraver) to a PercentRepeat grob, which will position a stencil. But we want to actually abuse a MultiMeasureRest grob to look like a percent repeat. But the percent is actually not an accessible symbol, but drawn using a C++-routine. So we have to create this stencil ourselves. Also this serves useful if you want to have percents with more than two slashes.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation, I think I understand now.