# Lilypond : Multi bar, multi repeat in one measure

Tags: lilypond, repeats, lily-scheme

Following [Lilypond: Single bar, multiple repeat](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/126276/lilypond-single-bar-multiple-repeat), I want this for a multi measure repeat.

I'm converted (./.) to  (.//.) with

```
percperc = \markup\concat{
  \raise #0.5 \musicglyph #"dots.dot"
  \hspace #-0.75
  \lower #1 \slash #2 #1 #0.98
  \hspace #-1.5
  \lower #1 \slash #2 #1 #0.98
  \hspace #-0.75
  \lower #0.5 \musicglyph #"dots.dot"
}
```

Now I need to get the measure bar (vertical line) in the middle.
I can't find this bar in the documentation, how can I insert it?

My goal is to shorten my music to be used in my marching booklet.
I don't have to have all measures with repeats written out, but just | notes | .//. | with the number above.

Comment: Please clarify what it is you actually want to achieve, if possible with an image.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve what is written in the mentioned thread.
The two measure repeat: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuuHs.png

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get visually reasonable output without having to draw everything by hand. It won't produce correct MIDI output. LilyPond thinks it's just two measures long, so you have to fix the bar number afterwards.

```
\version "2.24.2"

doublePercentWithCount =
  #(define-music-function (length count) (ly:duration? number?)
     (make-music 'DoublePercentEvent
                 'length (ly:duration-length length)
                 'repeat-count count ))

{
  c'1 1

  \set countPercentRepeats = ##t
  \after 1 \once \omit Score.BarNumber  % suppress bogus bar number in the middle of the repeat
  \doublePercentWithCount 1*2 999       % length 1*2 (two measures), with "999" printed over it
  \set Score.currentBarNumber = 2001

  d'1 1
}
```

`doublePercentWithCount` is adapted from [`makePercent` in the LilyPond documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/short-repeats#Isolated-percent-repeats).

Comment: This is a very nice, and small way of doing it.

And this can be made for 1 measure repeat also.
`PercentWithCount =
  #(define-music-function (length count) (ly:duration? number?)
     (make-music 'PercentEvent
                 'length (ly:duration-length length)
                 'repeat-count count ))

{
  c'1 1

  \set countPercentRepeats = ##t
  \doublePercentWithCount 1 999       % length 1*2 (two measures), with "999" printed over it
  \set Score.currentBarNumber = 2001

  d'1 1
}`